# What makes a display visible in daylight (such as the Pixel Qi)?

Tags: led, lcd, display

What characteristics of the [Pixel Qi](http://www.adafruit.com/products/1303) display make it visible under daylight conditions?

It seems to have something to do with "daylight grayscale".  But what exactly does "daylight grayscale" mean?  Is it something that can be accomplished/reproduced in software on any grayscale displays?  Can it be reproduced on a color display?

Comment: it's spelled Qi, not Qui

Comment: Display **contrast** makes a display visible in daylight

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The pixels are "transflective", meaning half-backlit and half-mirrored.

[image]